# OO approach to view controller classes in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, constructor

I have 10 different pages built into a slider control in my app, these pages are setup using storyboards.

The only difference on each page is a different web view to display rich text and a different image as a background are used.

Is it possible for me to have one view controller for all 10 pages and setup some flags in the constructor which would be executed on every page when its loaded to tell it what image and web view to show? If so what would this look like?

Thanks,

Lewis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create subclass of UIViewController, for example MyViewController.
And then replace your .h file with:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *myWebView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *myImageView;

- (id)initWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString image:(NSString *)imageName;

@end
```

And your .m file with:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize myWebView = _myWebView;
@synthesize myImageView = _myImageView;

- (id)initWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString image:(NSString *)imageName
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        _myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
        [_myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];

        _myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        _myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 400, 60, 60);
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And then just create an instances of your UIViewController subclass:

```
MyViewController *vCon = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithURLString:someURLString image:imageName];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although if I assign this subclass to all of my 10 views, and call the line to create an instance of the class in my didLoad then it will be the same in all of them? or are you suggesting I have this as a base class which my 10 other classes include, then I just call that line in their didLoads?

Comment: No, you should create two arrays with required information. One array with url strings, and another with image names.

Comment: And then in your main viewcontroller's didLoad method create a loop, within which you should create all ten view controllers and assign to their properties approach NSString objects from these arrays

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to define a data source for your view controller. This data source would have the following interface, e.g.:

```
@protocol MyVCDataSource
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPages;
- (NSString*)htmlContentForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSString*)backgroundForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

You would provide your view controller with a member called `datasource` that would be initialized in the `initWithDatasource` method:

```
@interface MyVC : UIViewController
...
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyVCDataSource> datasource;
- (id)initWithDatasource:(id<MyVCDataSource>)ds;
```

Then your view controller would just ask the data source for the HTML data or the background file name when it needs it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.view.backgroundColor = GET_BACKGROUND_FROM_STRING([self.datasource backgroundForPageIndex:self.currentIndex]);

    [self.webView loadHTMLString: [self.datasource htmlContentForPageIndex:self.currentIndex]];
....

}
```

I assumed that the protocol just returns strings, but indeed you can have it return what you need (e.g., an image, a color, an URL), it all depends on the internals of your class.

Finally, your datasource object could be any object (even your `MyVC` instance) and return its data by indexing into an array:

```
- (NSString*)htmlContentForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [self.htmlPages objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

etc.